# Apache Ignite 2.1: Getting a "Conflicting type IDs" error after upgrading from 2.0

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm getting the error "Conflicting type IDs [type1='Row', type2='Row', typeId=113114]" after upgrading from Apache Ignite 2.0 to 2.1 (.Net). I didn't change any code after upgrading, so am wondering if the expectation on how to create and use dynamic Binary Objects changed? I looked at the AddType method. Maybe it should be returning instead of throwing, and maybe the name of the method is misleading and it should be GetOrAddType?

AddType Method:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/efd299f401ea34e040037c76be0c9f86e0e8e239/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core/Impl/Binary/Marshaller.cs#L667

Stack Trace:

```
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.ThrowConflictingTypeError(Object type1, Object type2, Int32 typeId)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.AddType(Type type, Int32 typeId, String typeName, Boolean userType, Boolean keepDeserialized, IBinaryNameMapper nameMapper, IBinaryIdMapper idMapper, IBinarySerializerInternal serializer, String affKeyFieldName, Boolean isEnum)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.AddUserType(BinaryTypeConfiguration typeCfg, TypeResolver typeResolver)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.GetDescriptor(Boolean userType, Int32 typeId, Boolean requiresType, String typeName, Type knownType)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.GetDescriptor(String typeName)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Binary.GetBuilder(String typeName)
   at MyCompany.DataFabric.Core.CacheManagers.Table.RowCacheManager.BuildRow(Int64 rowNumber, String row, Boolean setColumnFields) in C:\Users\me\Documents\GitLab\Platform\Core\CacheManagers\Table\RowCacheManager.cs:line 140
   at MyCompany.DataFabric.Core.CacheManagers.Table.RowCacheManager.<>c__DisplayClass26_1.<WriteAsync>b__1(KeyValuePair`2 r) in C:\Users\me\Documents\GitLab\Platform\Core\CacheManagers\Table\RowCacheManager.cs:line 128
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
public async Task WriteAsync(IEnumerable<string> rows, long startRowNum = 0) {
    // Create the cache if it doesn't exist, yet
    await this.GetOrCreateRowCache();

    using (var ds = m_ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, object>(CacheName).WithKeepBinary<string, IBinaryObject>()) {
        try {
            ds.AllowOverwrite = true;
            ds.Receiver = new RowStreamReceiver {
                TableId = TableId
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(rows.Select((r, i) => new KeyValuePair<long, string>(i, r)), r => {
                var rowNum = r.Key + startRowNum;
                if (rowNum % 10000 == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Put [Row: {r.Key}, Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
                }
                var pair = BuildRow(rowNum, r.Value, false);
                // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
                ds.AddData(pair);
            });
        } finally {
            Console.WriteLine("Flushing");
            ds.Flush();
        }
    }
}

public KeyValuePair<string, IBinaryObject> BuildRow(long rowNumber, string row, bool setColumnFields = true) {
    var builder = m_ignite.GetBinary().GetBuilder(TypeName);

    var rowId = row.GetHashString();
    builder.SetField(PrimaryKeyName, rowId);
    builder.SetField(RowNumberName, rowNumber);
    builder.SetField(RawName, row);

    if (setColumnFields) {
        SetColumnFields(m_table, row, builder);
    }

    return new KeyValuePair<string, IBinaryObject>(rowId, builder.Build());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced and filed the bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5931

It's a race condition, and I think it exists in 2.0 as well (this piece of code is the same in 2.1 and 2.0). There are two other places where similar check is done correctly, expecting a multithreaded scenario, but this one was forgotten.

**Workaround 1**: register the type in `BinaryConfiguration`:

```
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
            {
                Types = new[] {"Row"}
            }
        };
```

**Workaround 2**: synchronize access to `GetBuilder` method (put it in a lock). Actual processing does not have to be in a lock, so the performance won't be affected.