# Conflicting field IDs error in Ignite C# thin client

Tags: c#, ignite, distributed-caching

I am trying to store entity in a Ignite-Cache using C# thin client.
I have below scenario

```
public class A
    {
        DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

When i am trying to store instance object of class B in ignite store it give me below error.

```
IgniteThinClient.GetCache<Tkey, TValue>("CacheName")
```

It gives me below error

Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryObjectException: 'Conflicting field IDs [type=B, field1=StartDate , field2=StartDate , fieldId=104069929]'

Similar issue links

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8588

[Apache Ignite 2.1: Getting a "Conflicting type IDs" error after upgrading from 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494512/apache-ignite-2-1-getting-a-conflicting-type-ids-error-after-upgrading-from-2)

How can I turn off binary object storing for C# thin client? Will that will help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have a class hierarchy like this? Usually this is a result of a mistake: either use `override` or `new` for a property with the same name in the derived class.

Comment: Even though I will use new or override for a property. It is still give same error.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out docs on [serialization](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/serialization). You could try to implement `IBinarizable` in B, and only write the field that you care about (or put both under differing names). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Is there other way to do this as I have huge number of entities with above issue?

Comment: Or is there any Ignore attribute for ignoring property?

Comment: I think you can try mark these properties with `[NotSerialized]`. Can you try that?